# Excel Match, Index function with And Not Functions

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am setting up a Spreadsheet where it is running reports for Tasks, The functions needed are `Match`, `Index`, `And` and `Not`.

The formulas that I have created individually work, however when I combine that they result in an error and return a Zero.

Please could anyone assist in combining the two formulas?

I have tried to just add the working formulas into the section

```
"SMALL(IF('Task Sheet'!$C$1:$C$385=Lists!$C$8,ROW" so that it read "SMALL(IF(AND('Task Sheet'!$C$1:$C$385=Lists!$C$8,NOT('Task Sheet'!$E$1:$E$385=Lists!$D$4)),ROW"
```

Code 1 - `=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('Task Sheet'!$A$1:$J$385,SMALL(IF('Task Sheet'!$C$1:$C$385=Lists!$C$8,ROW('Task Sheet'!$A$1:$J$385)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX('Task Sheet'!$A$1:$J$385,SMALL(IF('Task Sheet'!$C$1:$C$385=Lists!$C$8,ROW('Task Sheet'!$A$1:$J$385)),ROW(1:1)),2))`

Code 2 - `=IF(AND('Task Sheet'!$C$1:$C$385=Lists!$C$8,NOT('Task Sheet'!$E$1:$E$385=Lists!$D$4)),"x","")`

The expected result is that the report should result in any task that is outstanding which is not "Complete". Unfortunately it only results in a 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array formulas do not use `AND` and `OR`, on must use `*` and `+` respectively:

```
SMALL(IF(('Task Sheet'!$C$1:$C$385=Lists!$C$8)*('Task Sheet'!$E$1:$E$385<>Lists!$D$4),ROW...
```

Comment: Thanks, great solution